# MVC Validation Lower/Higher than other value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model, data-annotations

How is the best way to validate a model in MVC.Net where I want to accept a minimum/maximum.

Not individual min/max values for a field. But separate fields for a user to specify a minimum/maximum.

```
public class FinanceModel{
   public int MinimumCost {get;set;}
   public int MaximumCost {get;set;}
}
```

So I need to ensure that MinimumCost is always less than Maximum cost.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use a custom validation attribute here is my example with dates.
But you can use it with ints too.

First, here is the model :

```
public DateTime Beggining { get; set; }

[IsDateAfterAttribute("Beggining", true, ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(LocalizationHelper), ErrorMessageResourceName = "PeriodErrorMessage")]
public DateTime End { get; set; }
```

And here is the attribute itself :

```
public sealed class IsDateAfterAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private readonly string testedPropertyName;
    private readonly bool allowEqualDates;

    public IsDateAfterAttribute(string testedPropertyName, bool allowEqualDates = false)
    {
        this.testedPropertyName = testedPropertyName;
        this.allowEqualDates = allowEqualDates;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var propertyTestedInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(this.testedPropertyName);
        if (propertyTestedInfo == null)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(string.Format("unknown property {0}", this.testedPropertyName));
        }

        var propertyTestedValue = propertyTestedInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, null);

        if (value == null || !(value is DateTime))
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        if (propertyTestedValue == null || !(propertyTestedValue is DateTime))
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        // Compare values
        if ((DateTime)value >= (DateTime)propertyTestedValue)
        {
            if (this.allowEqualDates && value == propertyTestedValue)
            {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }
            else if ((DateTime)value > (DateTime)propertyTestedValue)
            {
                return ValidationResult.Success;
            }
        }

        return new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName));
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = this.ErrorMessageString,
            ValidationType = "isdateafter"
        };
        rule.ValidationParameters["propertytested"] = this.testedPropertyName;
        rule.ValidationParameters["allowequaldates"] = this.allowEqualDates;
        yield return rule;
    }
```

Comment: You need to complete this example with the client-side validation: 
`jQuery.validator.addMethod('isdateafter', function (value, element, params) {
  if (!/Invalid|NaN/.test(new Date(value))) {
    return new Date(value) > new Date();
  }
  return isNaN(value) && isNaN($(params).val()) || (parseFloat(value) > parseFloat($(params).val()));
}, '');
jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('isdateafter', {}, function (options) {
  options.rules['isdateafter'] = true;
  options.messages['isdateafter'] = options.message;
});`

Comment: There seems to be a bug due to the line `if (this.allowEqualDates && value == propertyTestedValue)`. This works: `if (this.allowEqualDates && value.Equals(propertyTestedValue))`  or even this `if (this.allowEqualDates && (DateTime)value == (DateTime)propertyTestedValue)`.

Answer (score 29):

There is a NuGet package called [Foolproof](http://foolproof.codeplex.com/) which provides these annotations for you. That said - writing a custom attribute is both pretty easy and good practice.

Using Foolproof would look like:

```
public class FinanceModel{
   public int MinimumCost {get;set;}

   [GreaterThan("MinimumCost")]
   public int MaximumCost {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Accepted the custom validator just as a learning tool. Thanks for the reference to Foolproof. Will keep it handy just incase anyway.

Comment: Foolproof does not seem to accept custom error messages.

Comment: Custom error messages are specified as such [GreaterThan("MinimumCost"), ErrorMessage = "Must be more than Minimum Cost"]

Comment: A little correction here: The error message should be like this, [GreaterThan("MinimumCost", ErrorMessage = "Must be more than Minimum Cost")]

Answer (score 6):

For client side validation using the allowEqualDates and propertyTested parameters (complement to Boranas answer above but too long for comment):

```
// definition for the isdateafter validation rule
if ($.validator && $.validator.unobtrusive) {
    $.validator.addMethod('isdateafter', function (value, element, params) {
        value = Date.parse(value);
        var otherDate = Date.parse($(params.compareTo).val());
        if (isNaN(value) || isNaN(otherDate))
            return true;
        return value > otherDate || (value == otherDate && params.allowEqualDates);
    });
    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('isdateafter', ['propertytested', 'allowequaldates'], function (options) {
        options.rules['isdateafter'] = {
            'allowEqualDates': options.params['allowequaldates'],
            'compareTo': '#' + options.params['propertytested']
        };
        options.messages['isdateafter'] = options.message;
    });
}
```

More information: [unobtrusive validation](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html), [jquery validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/)

Answer (score 1):

In VB for integers:

**MODEL**

```
<UtilController.IsIntegerGreatherOrEqualThan("PropertyNameNumberBegins", "PeriodErrorMessage")>
        Public Property PropertyNameNumberEnds As Nullable(Of Integer)
```

**VALIDATION**

```
Public Class IsIntegerGreatherOrEqualThan
        Inherits ValidationAttribute

        Private otherPropertyName As String
        Private errorMessage As String

        Public Sub New(ByVal otherPropertyName As String, ByVal errorMessage As String)
            Me.otherPropertyName = otherPropertyName
            Me.errorMessage = errorMessage
        End Sub

        Protected Overrides Function IsValid(thisPropertyValue As Object, validationContext As ValidationContext) As ValidationResult

            Dim otherPropertyTestedInfo = validationContext.ObjectType.GetProperty(Me.otherPropertyName)

            If (otherPropertyTestedInfo Is Nothing) Then
                Return New ValidationResult(String.Format("unknown property {0}", Me.otherPropertyName))
            End If

            Dim otherPropertyTestedValue = otherPropertyTestedInfo.GetValue(validationContext.ObjectInstance, Nothing)

            If (thisPropertyValue Is Nothing) Then
                Return ValidationResult.Success
            End If

            ''  Compare values
            If (CType(thisPropertyValue, Integer) >= CType(otherPropertyTestedValue, Integer)) Then
                Return ValidationResult.Success
            End If

            ''  Wrong
            Return New ValidationResult(errorMessage)
        End Function
    End Class
```

Comment: I removed "FormatErrorMessage" from the code as it was adding " 'The Field' + {errorMessage} + 'is invalid' ".  I was doing a date check, so I replaced Integer with Date.  Worked great and saved me time.  Thank you.

Comment: So errorMessage was displaying wrong message?, when I used it I didn't pay attention for it.

Comment: Not really wrong, just extra wording.  By using "Return new ValidationResult(errorMessage)" then it was good.

Answer (score -8):

Why you are not used Range Validator.
Syntax:

```
    [Range(typeof(int), "0", "100", ErrorMessage = "{0} can only be between {1} and {2}")]
    public int Percentage { get; set; }
```

Comment: If you look at my original question or the existing answers, you'll see the situation I'm trying to validate is where a user can select upper/lower bounds. Not when they have to enter a value between existing high/low values.