# How do I compare between two input dates?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to check that the expiration date is greater than another date.

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "0:yyyy/MM/dd", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? Date { get; set; }

[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "0:yyyy/MM/dd", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime? Expiration { get; set; }
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Can you please translate your question to English?

Comment: Modified as per my limited knowledge of la lingua Francais. Knowledge which consists of two years at school some *cough/sputter* decades ago and a week in Paris mid this year so, for all I know, OP may have been calling my parentage into question :-)

Comment: I'm french and i have to say that your translation is good :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom validator to check your different dates using `ValidationAttribute`.

Take a look of [this link.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18577850/1134380)

Answer (score 1):

for example

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
DateTime expiration = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);
if (expiration > date)
```

you can compare dates like this