# Range and DisplayFormat Attributes on TimeSpan

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I am building a Scheduling Screen and need to display a Time field for users to enter the time of day for the schedule.

I'm not sure if this is the best option, but I am using a TimeSpan for the field. To validate the input, I want to use the Range attribute and the DisplayFormat attribute.

When I debug and enter a seeming valid value, the Range attribute indicates an out of range error.  Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?  Is TimeSpan the proper type for this usage? Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Model Class:**

```
public class Schedule
{
    public Schedule()
    {
        this.ScheduleTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The time of day for the schedule to run
    /// </summary>
    [Required, DataType(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DataType.Time),
    Display(Name = "Schedule Time", Description = "Number of Hours and Minutes after Midnight Central Timezone"),
    DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = @"{0:hh\:mm\:ss}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true),
    Range(typeof(TimeSpan), "00:00", "23:59")]
    public TimeSpan ScheduleTime { get; set; }
}
```

**Error Message:**

[image: Error Message]

Comment: I'm not sure about the validation side, but I would use a `DateTime` object - `TimeSpan` represents a duration of time, while `DateTime` represents an actual time.

Comment: Thanks @TheEvilPenguin, I considered using DateTime but figured I would have to create a custom attribute to validate just the time. Also, the API I'm using has this value as a TimeSpan, so luckily I found the post I mentioned in my answer and it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know those times where you ask a question and shortly after the answer just appears right before you? This is one of those for me.

I found this SO post:
[why does ASP.Net MVC Range Attribute take a Type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366549/why-does-asp-net-mvc-range-attribute-take-a-type)

Which describes the issue as jQuery being unable to handle the Range expression so the Client Side Validation won't work, but the Server Side Validation will.

So I removed the client validation for this field with javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#ScheduleTime").rules('remove', 'range');
    });
</script>
```

And now the validation works properly when checking the `ModelState.IsValid` in the controller.

Answer (score 16):

I found this question while looking for a similar problem and I want to say for the records that range validation works well in ASPNET Core 2 and JQuery v2.2.0.

```
[Range(typeof(TimeSpan), "00:00", "23:59")]
```

Comment: This compiles but doesn't generate validation exceptions for me

Answer (score 7):

I know this is an old post, but i was able to keep the client side validation using a regular expression rather than the range validation like so:

```
    [Display(Name = "Schedule Time ")]
    [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:hh\\:mm}")]
    [RegularExpression(@"((([0-1][0-9])|(2[0-3]))(:[0-5][0-9])(:[0-5][0-9])?)", ErrorMessage = "Time must be between 00:00 to 23:59")]
    public System.TimeSpan? ScheduleTime { get; set; }
```