# jQuery rule to remove validation

Tags: jquery

I currently have an asp.net Mvc5 application which has a number of fields (Days of the week) as timespans. This is so a user can record their the amount of time they spend on a case. From reading [Range and DisplayFormat Attributes on TimeSpan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624766/range-and-displayformat-attributes-on-timespan) I found out that I needed to include the following

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#ScheduleTime").rules('remove', 'range');
});
```

This is fine and works on my first field. I changed the code to incorporate all of my fields like this.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Monday, #Tuesday, #Wednesday, #Thursday, #Friday, #Saturday, #Sunday").rules('remove', 'range');
});
```

The current view that I have is which is done through razor syntax

```
   <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Monday, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Monday, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Monday, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tuesday, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tuesday, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tuesday, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Wednesday, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Wednesday, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Wednesday, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Thursday, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Thursday, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Thursday, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Friday, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Friday, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Friday, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Saturday, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Saturday, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Saturday, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Sunday, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Sunday, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Sunday, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

However this doesn't work. How do I get around this?

Many thanks

Comment: What is the  `.rules()` jQuery plugin? Does it support selecting more than one element?

Comment: Show DOM please (markup example)

Comment: This is the jquery `rules()` plugin http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules/

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by just creating a new rule for each day. Not sure if this is the correct way but it has resolved my issue

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Monday").rules('remove', 'range');
        $("#Tuesday").rules('remove', 'range');
        $("#Wednesday").rules('remove', 'range');
        $("#Thursday").rules('remove', 'range');
        $("#Friday").rules('remove', 'range');
        $("#Saturday").rules('remove', 'range');
        $("#Sunday").rules('remove', 'range');
    });
```